# How to count clicks on an image in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a webpage where there is a button “Start frog game”.
Whenever the user clicks the button “Start frog game”:
● A message appears under the button saying “​Your score is 0​”;

● Under the score message, ​every half a second, ​one of the 5 images appears ​randomly​,
the image height should be 150 pixels;

● When the user clicks the ​frog image, then the user ​wins 1 point​, and the score message should be updated accordingly;

● When the user clicks other images, then the user ​loses 1 point​, and the score message should be updated accordingly (the score can become negative number if the user loses too much);

● When the score reaches 5, then the user wins the game and the game stops (images stop changing), the score message should display “​Your score is 5. Game over - You win!​”

● When the score goes down to -5, then the user loses the game and the game stops (images stop changing), the score message should display “​Your score is -5. Game over - You lose!​”
The user can click the button “Start frog game” to play the game again and the score should be reset to 0.

**WHAT I'VE DONE**:

Right now  have been able to create a webpage that counts the number of times that ANY IMAGE is clicked and have it display the score below.

**WHAT I NEED HELP WITH**:

I can't seem to figure out how to make the points increase ONLY when the frog image is clicked, and then make the points decrease when ONLY the other images (not the frog) are clicked.
I also am having trouble trying to make the images stop when the score reaches 5 (you win) or -5 (you lose).

Here is my code:

```js
function rollImages(){
  var counter = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (counter === 10000) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      return;
    }

    var imageValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
    var imageFile = "img" + imageValue + ".png";
    var theImage = document.getElementById("display");
    theImage.src = imageFile;
    counter++;
  }, 500);
}

var scoreClick = 0;
function score(){
  scoreClick = scoreClick + 1;
  var scoreSpan = document.getElementById("scoreDisplay");
  scoreSpan.innerHTML = scoreClick;
  if (scoreClick == 5){
    scoreDisplay.innerHTML = " Game over - you win!";
  }
}

function minusScore(){
  scoreClick = scoreClick - 1;
  var scoreSpan = document.getElementById("scoreDisplay");
  scoreSpan.innerHTML = scoreClick;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="rollImages()">Start frog game</button>
<br /><br />
<img height='150px' id="display" onclick="score()">
<br /><br />
<p id="score">Your score is:
<span id="scoreDisplay">0</span></p>
```

Comment: How do we know when am image is a frog image? I may be missing something but I can’t at the moment see how to distinguish as the images are selected just on number it seems. Which is the frog?

Comment: onClick test the attribute 'src' of the img to be that of the frog. in your onclick method recieve the 'event' paramater. event.target.src

Answer (score 0):

You need a way of identifying if the current image is a frog or not. You could do this by adding a class to the image whenever you `rollImages()`, or by checking its source, or by giving it an ID:

```js
function rollImages() {
  var counter = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (counter === 10000) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      return;
    }

    var imageValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
    var imageFile = "img" + imageValue + ".png";

    var theImage = document.getElementById("display");
    theImage.src = imageFile;
  
    if (imageValue === 1) {   // <--- Whatever imageValues correspond to frogs
      theImage.classList.add("frog");
    } else {
      theImage.classList.remove("frog");
    }

    counter++;
  }, 500);
}
```

Then your `score` function (you only need one) can determine if the image has the "frog" class or not, either add or remove a point, and fire the endgame states if need be:

```js
function score(event) {
  var img = event.target;
  if (img.classList.contains("frog") {
    scoreClick += 1;
  } else {
    scoreClick -+ 1;
  }

  var scoreSpan = document.getElementById("scoreDisplay");

  if (scoreClick >= 5) {
    scoreSpan.innerHTML = " Game over - you win!";
    return;
  }

  if (scoreClick <= -5) {
    scoreSpan.innerHTML = "LOSER!";
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to modify anything in the body?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to distinguish between frog and non-frog images is to use an array. Store the five image URIs in an array, and let arr[0] be the frog, Then randomize the image from 0 to 4. When the index is 0 you know that the frog image is showing.

Answer (score 0):

so the idea is to create 5 images ing the html code, to the frog image - onclick="frog", and the rest - onclick="notfrog()",
in the javascript file create function wich reapets every 500ms, and make one random image appeare,
another function - frog(), wich doing score++, and checking if score==5,
the last function is the notfrog(), pretty similar to the last function, just - score--, and checks if score==-5,

heres my code:

**html**

```html
<style>
    img{
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <img src="./images/frog.jpg" onclick="frog()" id="frog">
    <img src="./images/monkey.jpg" onclick="notfrog()">
    <img src="./images/bird.jpg" onclick="notfrog()">
    <img src="./images/lion.jpg" onclick="notfrog()">
    <img src="./images/giraffe.jpg" onclick="notfrog()">

    <span id="score">0</span>
</body>
```

**javascript**

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
var score_html = document.getElementById('score');
var score = 0;
var repeat_fn = setInterval(function choose_image(){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    images[random].style.display = 'block';
    for(var i = 0; i<=images.length; i++){
        if(i != random){
            images[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}, 500)
function frog(){
    score++;
    if(score === 5){
        score_html.innerHTML = "you won";
        score = 0;
    }
    else{

        score_html.innerHTML = score;
    }
}
function notfrog(){
    score--;
    score_html.innerHTML = score;
    if(score === -5){
        score_html.innerHTML = "you lost";
        score = 0;
    }
}
```